# Why are my classes in subfolders all interpreted as external?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, t4, envdte

When I iterate and search through `envDTEProject.CodeModel.CodeElements` I'm using the [CodeElement.InfoLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeelement.infolocation.aspx) property in order to distinguish my own classes from external classes.

Problem is that this only returns the expected value, `vsCMInfoLocationProject`, for classes directly in the root of the project, all of my other classes (and namespaces) that are placed in subfolders in the project are returning `vsCMInfoLocationExternal`.

This makes no sense to me. Is this a bug or have I misunderstood something?

---

The only thing I can find is that something similar seems to [have been reported as a bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de79cec5-5e3d-453a-a50a-012bd0f6cdd6/codenamespaceinfolocation-always-is-vscminfolocationvscminfolocationexternal?forum=vsx) 11 years ago (but the link to the bug report itself is dead) and [a very recent bug here](https://github.com/madskristensen/TypeScriptDefinitionGenerator/issues/17) that unfortunately for me disappeared when they updated visual studio to 26430.15, the same build that I have now.

When I move a class to the root, it shows as Project. When I drag it to a subfolder, it shows as External.

The bug is still present in VS2019 Preview 3.

Comment: What type of project are you using? Some (e.g. some web based ones) use a mixed compilation model where some code is compiled during build and others during startup/runtime.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's a Web API project, but they are simple plain classes that are there in the executable when I inspect it using DotPeek.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Clarification: It's a ASP.NET Core Application project, using the Web API template.